# Get sinus of an angle from a distance x and two circumferences of different radius

Tags: trigonometry

How is possible to get these formulas of sinus from this image?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s6Af.jpg

I have been trying different things but they didn't work out.

Comment: Draw radius that connects circle centre with the point where line is tangent to the circle.

Comment: @Matteo Use the fact that they are perpendicular.

Comment: Thanks to both!